# How to get a string inside a specific string?

Tags: c#

Suppose I have this string:

```
string test = "var block = new MatchesBlock('page_competition_1_block_competition_matches_summary_5', 'block_competition_matches_summary', {"page":0,"bookmaker_urls":{"13":[{"link":"http:\/\/www.bet365.com\/home\/?affiliate=365_178981","name":"Bet 365"}]},"block_service_id":"competition_summary_block_competitionmatchessummary","round_id":42011,"outgroup":false,"view":2,"competition_id":13});"
```

how can I get the content inside `MatchesBlock`?
In particular this json:

```
'page_competition_1_block_competition_matches_summary_5', 'block_competition_matches_summary', {"page":0,"bookmaker_urls":{"13":[{"link":"http:\/\/www.bet365.com\/home\/?affiliate=365_178981","name":"Bet 365"}]},"block_service_id":"competition_summary_block_competitionmatchessummary","round_id":42011,"outgroup":false,"view":2,"competition_id":13}
```

Comment: What is `MatchesBlock`?

Comment: Try a regex. `MatchesBlock\((.+?)\)` -- lazily capture anything between the brackets.

Comment: find first index of `MatchesBlock(`, then index of `);` after it, and get the substring. Where do you get the string from, .js file? Seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Slai is not simple as you pointed out. The content of `test` is part of this javascript function: https://pastebin.com/3XGADziW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a Regular Expression. To achieve your specific results you could do something like this:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"MatchesBlock\(([^)]+)\)");
foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(@"var block = new MatchesBlock('page_competition_1_block_competition_matches_summary_5', 'block_competition_matches_summary', {""page"":0,""bookmaker_urls"":{""13"":[{""link"":""http:\/\/www.bet365.com\/home\/?affiliate=365_178981"",""name"":""Bet 365""}]},""block_service_id"":""competition_summary_block_competitionmatchessummary"",""round_id"":42011,""outgroup"":false,""view"":2,""competition_id"":13});")) {
    var yourtext = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

This regular expression can be broken down as:

1. `MatchesBlock\(` -> Matches the text up to the opening parenthesis
2. `(` -> Start a capturing group
3. `[^)]+` -> captures everything that is not a closing parenthesis
4. `)` -> ends the capturing group
5. `\)`-> matches a closing parenthesis

But your approach is naive. You should really be using something more robust, like a parser for the specific language (looks like JavaScript). Unless you really, really just need this value.

Without knowing your exact requirements, sitting here, from afar with the autumn sun of Rio de Janeiro shining through my window, this looks like a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) to me. Isn't there another way to make it work avoiding parsing source code?

Comment: thanks but its possible take only the json without page_competition_1...?

Comment: @fantaghiro you asked for this part of the string int he question itself! Take a look at it! You've asked for: `"'page_competition_1_block_competition_matches_summary_5', 'block_competition_matches_sum..."` Of course it is possible to match only the JSON part, but that would take another regular expression I'll have to think on it a little bit.

Comment: `take only the json` -- you can try grabbing everyting between the first and  and the last curly braces, inclusive -- `MatchesBlock\(.+?({.*})\)` https://regex101.com/r/zGMdKt/1/

Comment: @LyoshaKorogoda it could work, if the JSON will never contains curly braces itself inside it! I really believe this is a code smell and that there is a better, alternative way to accomplish what the opener asked.

Comment: This JSON already contains curly braces inside it, and it works fine. We just lazily look for the first one and greedily for the last one.

Comment: I agree though that the whole idea of cutting strings out of some .js file looks like an XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

Would this suffice?

```
var startTrimmed = test.Replace("var block = new MatchesBlock(", string.Empty");
var endTrimmed = startTrimmed.Replace(");", string.Empty);
```

Comment: I can't do that, because the `test` content is part of this function: https://pastebin.com/3XGADziW so I should evaluate the string of pastebin